# Почему индекс в методе pop находится вне границы?

Tags: python

```
import random
WORDS = ["Svitanok", "hogog", "gfgfgfg", "sdasd", "adam"]
newwords = []
length = len(WORDS)
newpos = ""
while WORDS:
  newpos = random.randint(0, length-1)
  newwords.append(WORDS.pop(newpos))
  WORDS.remove(WORDS[newpos])
print(newwords)
```

В общем, писал алгоритм для вывода списка WORDS в случайном порядке. И наткнулся на ошибку "pop index out of range". Не могу понять, почему метод выходит за границы?
P.S. Про **shuffle** я знаю, просто хочу написать код таким способом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove` не нужно вызывать, `pop` уже удаляет элемент из списка. Кроме этого, значение `length` нужно обновлять на каждой итерации, тк список `WORDS` изменяет свой размер.

Comment: Спасибо, про length я как-то вообще забыл)

Answer (score 1):

Раз: допустим, после нескольких итераций WORDS у нас стал `["Svitanok"]`.

1)

```
newpos = random.randint(0, length-1)
```

newpos может быть 0, 1, 2, 3 или 4, потому что length=5 (никто эту переменную не менял) и length-1=4, а randint включает обе границы в интервал, из которого выбирается число.

Допустим, newpos выпало 4.

2)

```
newwords.append(WORDS.pop(newpos))
```

`"Svitanok"` это 0. Элементов, соответствующих индексам 1, 2, 3 или 4 здесь уже нет. А newpos у нас выпало как раз 4 — всё, выход за правый предел списка, pop падает.

---

Два: пройдёмся с самого начала с другой ситуацией

1)

```
newpos = random.randint(0, length-1)
```

Допустим, пусть там выпадет 4

2)

```
newwords.append(WORDS.pop(newpos))
```

WORDS = `["Svitanok", "hogog", "gfgfgfg", "sdasd"]`

newwords = `["adam"]`

3)

```
WORDS.remove(WORDS[newpos])
```

`"Svitanok"` это 0, `"hogog"` это 1, `"gfgfgfg"` это 2, `"sdasd"` это 3. А `newpos` у нас 4. Вот, собственно, и всё, `WORDS[newpos]` падает, ибо 4 это выход за правый предел списка.

---

Правильный код:

```
import random
WORDS = ["Svitanok", "hogog", "gfgfgfg", "sdasd", "adam"]
newwords = []
while WORDS:
  newpos = random.randint(0, len(WORDS) - 1)
  newwords.append(WORDS.pop(newpos))
print(newwords)
```

Comment: Алсо, однострочник по хардкору: `newwords = [WORDS.pop(random.randrange(len(WORDS))) for _ in range(len(WORDS))]`

Comment: Спасибо!) Жаль, репутацию пока поднять не могу)